# IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Tags: python, numpy

I am working on the snippet

```
top[0].data[128,0:128] = (fc1[self.keep1.tolist()])[self.keep2[128].tolist()]
```

keep1 has the data

```
[
  0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, ...... 114.0, 115.0, 116.0, 117.0, 118.0, 119.0
]
```

keep2 has the data

```
[ 
   125.  800.  255.  119.  801.  804.  114.  368.  636.  308.  805.  213.
   ......218.   373.
]
```

I got a problem saying "IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices"

I tried  self.keep2[128].tolist().astype(int), but it does say tolist() has no method astype(int)

how could I solve it?

Comment: You are trying to index a list as though it were an `numpy` array.  Make sure you understand the difference.   `arr.tolist()` makes a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `top[0].data`, `fc1`, `self.keep1` and `self.keep2` are all `numpy` arrays you are making your solution too complicated, when you turn your variables into lists. It is sufficient to do

```
top[0].data[128,0:128] = (fc1[self.keep1.astype(int)])[self.keep2[128].astype(int)]
```

if the dimensions are correct.

You should also ask yourself why `keep1` and `keep2` are floats and not ints to begin with. Are they the result of some float calculation? And in that case, can you be sure they do not have any fractional part?